# Unable to see the resource files after localization is true

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization

I have localized a Form say `BanksForm` into two languages by setting the `Localizable` property to `true` and setting the Language from `Default` to `French`.

Visual Studio generated the resource files and compiles them into the application. This is what I expected, but I am not able to see the resource file for my form and it does not generate the resource file for French language.

Would anyone please help on this?

Comment: would any one pls help on this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiled french resources will be stored in a dll named `myapp.resources.dll` located in the fr subdirectory of your app, e.g. as

`c:\mysolution\myapp\bin\release\fr\myapp.resources.dll`